# Как можно расположить кнопки как на скрине?

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout, android-library, android-view

Мне нужно так же расположить кнопки как тут, пробовал и через grid, и просто LinearLayout, никак не выходит, тут у каждой кнопки своя ширина и если кнопка не помещается она уходит на следующую кнопку.

[image]

Comment: Вы уже 6, вроде, человек, кто за последние пару месяцев это спрашивает. Расскажите, пж-та, почему вы задались этим вопросом()

Comment: Благодарю за ссылку. Не знал что уже подобный вопрос задавали, нужно было побольше помучить поиск...